# Updating two table by sequence on mongodb with expressjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, routes

I am trying to build an app with mern.
I wrote 2 routing `/api/roles` and `/api/users` like this:

```
app.use("/api/users", users);
app.use("/api/roles", roles);
```

what I want to do is create new roles and update the users,
my model has linkage with user and roles,
what is the best practice for this other then I copy all the roles function to users?

Comment: As I understand, you should separate logic into two models - users and roles, and update separately users and roles from outside

Comment: i needs to update roles first and return the id value to frontend and call users with the id?

Comment: No, by outside I mean outside function call. May be you need another model (not conected with db table, just abstract model) that call role model for creating new role, get its id and updateing needed user